# LIBGDX. Is there a way to make a Vector2 stop having constant velocity at an exact point?

Tags: libgdx

For example, say I have something moving at a constant speed with position myposition downwards using something like this:

```
myposition.add(velocity.scl(delta));
//position is a Vector2 and velocity is a Vector2 with a negative y value to make the position become more negative.
//here is where the texture/sprite gets drawn with myposition.y.
```

However, I'd like to know if there's a way I can make the object stop dead at a point such as when the y coordinate of the moving object is 0 (the ground), without going past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform the checks for a boundary crossing yourself and account for the potential "overlap" e.g.:

```
velocity.scl(delta);
boolean willPassZero = myposition.y + velocity.y <= 0;
myposition.add(velocity);
if ( willPassZero )
    myposition.y = 0;
```

If you know that your y position will always be >= 0, you could also use Math.clamp to pull the y component up to 0 once it crosses the 0 boundary.